# Word problem I think is unsolvable

Tags: word-problem

I am trying to help my 15 year old with her Critical Thinking homework. She has the entire worksheet finished except for this one problem. I want to help her but I don't even know how to start with this one. I would really like to learn how to solve it. Here is the math problem...

---

Photographs of students are taken and offered for sale in various packages.

2 large and 3 small: \\\$8.00

3 large and 3 small: \\\$9.00

4 large and 2 small: \\\$11.00

These prices include the same amount for postage and packaging.

What is the cost of postage and packaging included in these prices?

---

Please help me understand how to solve this.

Thank you.

Comment: If you let $L$ be the price of one large photo, $S$ the price of one small photo, and $P$ the cost of postage and packing, can you express the price of the first package in terms  of $L$,  $S$, and $P$?

Comment: When I set up three equations for $L$, $S$, and $P$ and solved them, I got a negative number for $S$.  Is there a typo.?

Comment: The data are inconsistent, unless the price of a small photo is $-\$1.00$.

Comment: My daughter also got a negative number for S. That is why she thought she was doing it wrong. What I posted here is the same as the worksheet. Maybe there's a typo on the worksheet.

Comment: She is going to submit it with the packaging as $9. I will update this with the teacher's response.

Comment: Yeah, maybe it is a trick question with the small photo really costing -1? Anyway I get $9 too.

Comment: small photo costing $-1$ is more implausible than that there is a typo in the problem.

Comment: The teacher responded and there was a typo in the question. The $9 option should be 3 large and 2 small. Thanks everyone for your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Thanks for getting back to us

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prices don’t make sense but here is an attempt to make sense of them.
$$2L+3S+P=\$8\land 3L+3S+P=\$9 \implies L=$1$$
By logic, then
$$ 4L+3S+P=\$10\quad\text{ but}\quad 4L+2S+P=\$11\implies S=-\$1$$
Back to the original
$$2L+3S+P=2(\$1)+3(-\$1)+P=-\$1+P=\$8\implies P=\$9$$
$$3L+3S+P=3(\$1)+3(-\$1)+P=\$0+P=\$8\implies P=\$9$$
$$4L+2S+P=4(\$1)+2(-\$1)+P=\$2+P=\$11\implies P=\$9$$

Comment: Did you see (in the comments) there was a typo.?

Comment: @J. W. Tanner Too long for a comment, (maybe). I just wanted to make sure she had all the steps needed to show that books sometimes do not get enough proofreading. :)